# Verification for maximum principle

Tags: optimization, control-theory, maximum-principle

Given optimal control problem
$$
\dot x = f(t,x(t),u(t)), \quad x(0) = x_0,\\
J(u) = \int_0^T f^0(t,x(t),u(t))dt \to \min,
$$
we can apply Pontryagin's maximum principle to get a necessary condition for an optimum.

My question is when maximum principle is sufficient and how do we verify that an obtained control function is optimal?

Comment: The Hamilton Jacobi-Bellman-equation gives a sufficient condition. But since this is a pde it is often hard to use. A suffcient condition should be, if the second derivative of $J$, lets say $J''$, is positiv definite. Then you have at least a LOCAL minimal point.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on restrictions of control $u$. If $u$ belongs to open set (for example $u\in\mathbb{R}$) then you can apply [Legendre–Clebsch condition](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Legendre_condition) and [Jacobi equation](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Jacobi_condition) to prove weak optimality. Also you can combine them with [Weierstrass condition](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Weierstrass_conditions_%28for_a_variational_extremum%29) to prove strong optimality. For your case you can find these conditions in [this](http://books.google.ru/books/about/Lectures_on_the_calculus_of_variations.html?id=pZ8XAQAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) book

If $u$ belongs to not open set (for example $u\in [-1;1]$) then above methods do not work. If the problem is convex or concave then you can use [Karush–Kuhn–Tucker theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) for Banach spaces -- it is equvilent to Pontryagen maximum principle but gives you sufficient conditions for optimality. If there is no convexity you may try to apply some second order conditions (see [Ioffe Tikhomirov](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=faa&paperid=2724&option_lang=eng)) but it is usually hard to verify them. Also there is Bellman PDE which gives you sufficint condition but it is necessary to construct optimal synthesis to verify it.